# Dropzone.js Auto Rotate Image

Tags: dropzone.js

When using Dropzone.js to upload and resize, I would like to also rotate to match EXIF rotation data.  Is this possible?

I cant seem to find anything about it on the Dropzone so I assume not?

Searched https://www.dropzonejs.com/ and Google.  All solutions seem to be external, which I am not sure how to then integrate with DZ

```
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            resizeWidth: 1920, 
            resizeHeight: 1080,
            resizeMethod: "contain", 
            resizeQuality: 1.0,
            paramName: "file",
            maxFilesize: 10,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg",
            createImageThumbnails: true,
```

All uploaded (and resized files), to be hard code rotated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Dropzone (tested with 5.4.0), it will automatically fix the orientation for thumbnails, as long as you include the exif.js library in your page:

```
https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js
```

It's from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765456/dropzonejs-javascriptloadimage-rotate-image). Hope that will help you.

Comment: This is not required for latest dropzone versions, and the bug still remains if the client-side image resize settings are used regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a patched version of Dropzone that should handle the EXIF orientation correctly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropzone-exif-fix

Credit for the patch goes to Kaymes on GitHub (https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/pull/2001)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug with dropzone](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/issues/1967), where if you are using resizeWidth/resizeHeight, and then uploading a large file with EXIF rotation data, the resize operation applies the EXIF information, but then the EXIF data is restored to the image.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/pull/2001) to fix the issue, however this hasn't been merged in, and this issue exists still today in both latest stable (v5.9.3) and beta versions (v6.0.0-beta.2). Someone has released a patched version of 5.9.3 with this fix applied here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropzone-exif-fix

If you use that patched version, uploads should work with EXIF data maintained. On your server you can then apply the orientation and strip the EXIF data before using the image further, or alternatively, you can leave the browser to handle using the [image-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation) css property.

Answer (score 0):

More information:  With Dropzone 5.7.2 I suddenly find you don't need to include the exif-js library.  Removing that and all works well and rotation is automatic.  Also I'm just testing with 5.9.2 and that autorotates also.

Comment: I'm using version 5.9.3 and I can confirm that both with and without the exif-js library being included, the image orientation is incorrect when using the resize options. Not sure how 5.9.2 or 5.7.2 were working for you - were you using the resize options? If you don't use those, then it doesn't do anything with orientation so far as I can tell, beyond what the browser does by default for the thumbnail.

Comment: Yes - I am resizing.  Resizing on the client, to give fast upload times, was one of the reasons I tested and then used Dropzone.  Having got it working, I haven't touched it for a year, but it still works for a user, I understand.   

Here are some the options used in a test program that did work.
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  // resizeWidth: 800,
  resizeHeight: 600,
  resizeMethod: 'contain', // [contain] 'crop' - crop to fit maxwidth / maxheight.
  resizeQuality: 0.8, // Default 0.8.      
  paramName: "file",  
  maxFilesize: 10,   
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.log",  etc.

Comment: Very strange. Those are basically the exact same settings I was using, and with the same Dropzone version - but for specific files with specific EXIF orientations, DropZone rotates them incorrectly for me (portrait image will be uploaded as a resized landscape one)

Comment: I just looked again at my test.  There is one thing you need to work around.  Dropbox does not strip the orientation tag out, or change it, so the uploaded file shows in the wrong orientation after upload at least in Windows.  I just strip the EXIF information out in my PHP upload processor.  Then all is fine.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I'm seeing - the EXIF tag doesn't match the image, so any EXIF aware applications will show it being incorrectly. In my case we're uploading it directly to blob storage rather than to our server.

Here's a version of Dropzone that includes the patch that fixes this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropzone-exif-fix